# Reason for name "Motile sperm domain-containing protein 2" if it has nothing to do with sperm

Tags: genetics, gene, nomenclature, gene-annotation

I am interested in a gene with the name "motile sperm domain-containing protein 2".

The entry for the human gene in [uniprot](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q8NHP6) suggests that it does not have any relation to sperm or spermatogenesis.

If this is so, why does the name make reference to sperm?

Comment: Please read the Tour as a new user to this site and especially how to ask good questions. Then, do some research yourself. Have you looked up the original papers on this protein or any reviews. They may be able to clarify a question of terminology. If you have to post, give a reference to the gene (Uniprot number and link) and tell us what organism it is in. Otherwise your question is unlikely to receive responses and is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Hi, I have checked many references and no chance!

Comment: Organism? Reference? Please read comments carefully before replying.

Comment: Hi David and thank you for your helps. There is not any organism or references that I can mention and there is no difference that this gene is expressing in which organism! we have a sequence of nucleotides that its annotation is refering to "motile sperm ...", So it is not important that this gene is expressing where in the animal kingdom. about the reference, it is not important to mention (I have mentioned one). many annotation database share same names, uniprot, trembl, NCBI. please attention that my question is this"why we use sperm in a gene name that is not working in sperm?"thats all.

Comment: Also asked [on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/284650/)

Comment: But eventually you are someone else did provide a link and I edited your question to indicate the species and take into account the content of the link. @DevonRyan has provided you with an answer. I suggest you accept it.

Comment: @FarbodEmami Note that you don't *have* to accept an answer if you don't believe it adequately answers your question (or if you believe the way in which it answers the question is unsatisfactory).

Answer (score 2):

As you can tell from the gene name, it contains a domain (a "[major sperm protein](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/entry/IPR000535) domain)") that happens to have "sperm" in its name. That doesn't mean that the protein itself have anything to do with sperm. There are a lot of examples of gene names like this, where they're named after some random domain they contain until later their names are changed. MSOPD2 has only had a known function for [a few months](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28137892).

As an aside, if you actually work on this gene then one would hope that you would have taken the whopping 5 minutes required to figure this out in pubmed.

Comment: Downvoted for the belittling snark of the "aside". If you think this question is too simple to be worth a Q&A on this StackExchange, then don't write an answer - downvote or vote-to-close and move on.